# Chromecast CAF and IMA SDK not works togeather

Tags: javascript, chromecast, receiver, imasdk

The latest Google Chromecast API has native ads functionality it supports VAST and VMAP formats, but we have found that if XML manifest file has type="aplication *" so the ads not work, chomecast ads functionality ignore this. [Google cast issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119569445) Any idea of this?
Ok, alterative solution was to use IMA sdk instead of standard CAF ads functionality.  But I cannot start to play ads, there are always an error.
I have used example of this code: [google ima sdk example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-cast)
after media loads I have added timeout for 15 seconds and than load an ad, like this:

```
playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
    cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, loadRequestData => {
        Utils.initIMA();
        setTimeout(()=>{
            playerManager.stop();
            Utils.requestAd('https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator=12345678');
        }, 15000);
        return loadRequestData;
    });
var Utils = {
    requestAd: (adTagUrl) => {
        let adsRequest = new google.ima.AdsRequest();
        adsRequest.adTagUrl = adTagUrl;
        adsRequest.linearAdSlotWidth = mediaElement.width;
        adsRequest.linearAdSlotHeight = mediaElement.height;
        adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotWidth = mediaElement.width;
        adsRequest.nonLinearAdSlotHeight = mediaElement.height / 3;
        adsLoader.requestAds(adsRequest);
    },
    initIMA : () => {
        let adDisplayContainer = new google.ima.AdDisplayContainer(document.getElementById('adContainer'), mediaElement);
       adDisplayContainer.initialize();
       adsLoader = new google.ima.AdsLoader(adDisplayContainer);
       adsLoader.getSettings().setPlayerType('cast/client-side');
       adsLoader.addEventListener(
           google.ima.AdsManagerLoadedEvent.Type.ADS_MANAGER_LOADED, 
           Utils.onAdsManagerLoaded, false);
       adsLoader.addEventListener(
           google.ima.AdErrorEvent.Type.AD_ERROR,   Utils.onAdError, false);
       adsLoader.addEventListener(
            google.ima.AdEvent.Type.ALL_ADS_COMPLETED, Utils.onAllAdsCompleted, false);
    }
}
```

Error reproduced on this line: adsLoader.requestAds(adsRequest);
Uncaught TypeError: a.g.canPlayType is not a function

Comment: Any progress on this? Seeing similar things!

Comment: No. Still the same situation. If you have type="application..." then you will not see this ads. google cast support team can not resolve this issue. So you need to configure your ads.